# Post API using fetch() is failing

Tags: javascript

According to Example:
I was supposed to receive the model and the text.

Because of some random error,
it is getting only model info.
But, if I do same thing using jQuery, I receive model + text;
So, do you understand the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="btn" onclick="createpdf()">Try</button>
<script>
const url = 'https://chatgpt-api8.p.rapidapi.com/';
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '***',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'chatgpt-api8.p.rapidapi.com'
    },
    body: [
        {
            content: 'who won the super bowl 2019?',
            role: 'user'
        }
    ]
};

try {
    const response = fetch(url, options)
     .then(response => response.json())
        .then(geocodeapi => {
            console.log(geocodeapi)
        })
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried jQuery it worked, but I tried many methods and using fetch and they didn't work.

Please help me.

Comment: You can't use try/catch with `.then`

Comment: You need to JSON.stringify the request body.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `fetch` without the `try/catch` because you can add a `catch` to your  `then` like so:

```
fetch(url, options)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(geocodeapi => {
   console.log(geocodeapi)
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```